# How to stop the view variables from getting overridden in Zend Framwork?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an action which sets a view variable called "categories" as shown below.

```
class CategoryController extends Zend_Controller_Action 
{
    public function indexAction() 
    {       
            $this->view->categories = 'A list of categories';
    }
}
```

Now the categories variable is used inside the layout to display the list of categories.

But the problem here is this, I have bunch of other actions which are called using front controller plugins and the "categories" variable is overwritten by one of the actions.

Is there a way to prevent the value of categories variable from getting overwritten? I.e. Using something I might be able to store the categories variable generated by the category->index action and other actions and access both in my layout.

I can always change the name of my variables but still would appreciate if there is any other solution to this.

Also, can I achieve this using named response segments?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you might be able to provide Zend_Layout with a different view object then the one assigned in the view renderer

Answer (score 1):

maybe you add a detect on other action when value is setting, and index action direct setting value.

other action,

```
if(!isset($this->view->categories))$this->view->categories='xxx';
```

category->index action

```
$this->view->categories = 'A list of categories';
```